# Quero colocar dentro de um ARRAY já existente as informações de um arquivo de texto .TXT com PHP

Tags: php, array, tradução

A ideia e fazer a tradução de um sistema em PHP, onde cada chave do ARRAY é uma tradução.

De forma manual eu já consegui retirar todas as chaves e traduzir elas, separar cada chave traduzida em uma linha, colocando todas em um arquivo de texto.txt, agora quero colocar essas linhas já traduzidas dentro do ARRAY como VALOR, puxando automaticamente do arquivo de texto.txt

Ex:

```
<?php
$lang["CHAVE"] ="VALOR";
?>
```

Parte do código é esse:

```
<?php
$lang["Signup"]              ="";
$lang["Sign In"]             ="";
$lang['Login Successful']    ='';
?>
```

Tem que ficar assim:

```
<?php
$lang["Signup"]              ="Inscrição";
$lang["Sign In"]             ="Entrar";
$lang['Login Successful']    ="Login com êxito";
?:>
```

Esse arquivo tem mais de 2600 linhas, todas nesse padrão, por isso quero automatizar esse trabalho, tem mais arquivos como esse para fazer.

Reparei que ainda tem muitos scripts em PHP que utilizam essa forma de tradução, seria interessante montar um script para fazer esse trabalho automatizado.

Arquivo texto.txt

```
Inscrição
Entrar
Login com êxito
```

Comment: Qual é o formato do arquivo TXT? Pode colocar as primeiras linhas para temos noção de como os dados estão nele.

Comment: Apenas texto puro, uma frase por linha.

Comment: E como é que vai ser possível associar cada linha à uma chave correspondente no array? Se o formato da linha fosse algo como CHAVE=texto traduzido, seria possível. Porém, parece que só há o texto traduzido. Como vamos saber se uma linha pertence à chave Signup ou se pertence à Sign in, por exemplo?

Comment: A ideia e cada linha corresponder a uma chave em ordem sequencial EX:
Primeiro registro do ARRAY
$lang["Signup"]              ="Inscrição";

1 linha do arquivo TXT -> Inscrição

Answer (score 0):

Embora eu entenda ser uma péssima lógica a proposta pela pergunta, acho que isto soluciona a questão:

```php
$lang = ['Signup', 'Sign in', 'Login successfull'];

foreach ($lang as $key => $value) {
    $txt = trim(fgets($file_handle))
    $lang[$key] = $txt;
}
```

Note que omiti o código de abertura/fechamento do arquivo de texto (que poderá ser feito por `fopen()` e `fclose()`.

Também assumi que o arquivo texto não possui linhas em branco no ínicio e no meio das traduções.

Comment: Entendo, meu problema e a demora na tradução dos sistemas, como você faria as traduções de uma forma mais rápida? 
Arquivos com 4 ou 5 mil linhas, hoje eu faço uma linha por vez. isso me leva dias apenas para traduzir.

Comment: A questão não é a tradução em si, mas sim você estar obrigado a seguir a mesma ordem no arquivo com as traduções que a ordem das chaves da variável ```$lang```. No mínimo, deveria haver uma chave no arquio de traduções para cada chave em ```$lang```. A muitos anos atrás eu escrevi uma ferramenta para internacionalização com PHP: https://github.com/everton3x/AlText e https://github.com/everton3x/i81n Dê uma olhada nelas para entender o conceito.